# Axios won't send cookie, Ajax (xhrFields) does just fine

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

Using Axios

```
export function sendAll() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(requestData());
    return axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `${C.API_SERVER.BASEURL}/notification/sendAll`,
      data: {prop: 'val'},
      // responseType: 'json',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      withCredentials: true
    }).then((response) => {
      dispatch(receiveData(response));
    }).catch((response) => {
      dispatch(receiveError(response));
      // dispatch(pushState(null, '/error'));
    })
  }
};
```

Result using Axios

[image: Chrome network tab when using Axios]

Using $.ajax

```
$.ajax({
  url: " http://local.example.com:3001/api/notification/sendAll",
  method: "post",
  data: {},
  crossDomain: true,
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  }
})
```

Result using $.ajax

[image: Chrome network tab when using $.ajax]

I am unable to force Axios to send a POST when trying to attach data to POST (cookie doesnt get sent either way).
My server setup (express):

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", `${C.PROTOCOL}://${C.DOMAIN}:${C.PORT}`);
  res.header("Access-Control-Request-Headers", "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  next();
});
```

I do not have a OPTIONS route defined. I want Axios to send POST with cookie.

```
router.post('/notification/sendAll', function (req, res, next) {
  res.sendStatus(204);
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Check last comment here: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/475

Comment: @Dekel Seems like I overflew this, thanks.

Answer (score 24):

I was facing a similar issue. Making a get/post request through Axios did not sent the same headers as a straight XHR request.

Then I just added the following just after the Axios require statement:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

After that Axios started sending my cookie like the regular XHR request did.

Comment: axios seems to handle the credentials differently when doing cors or non cors request. On non-cors I did not have to set withCreditials to true and it send the cookie but on cors it did not send the cookie until I explicitly told it to

Comment: Guys, AXIOS & CORS made me spent about two hours to solve - why NODEJS change session ids with every request. Now I am happy.

Comment: Echoing this here. It's crazy that setting the defaults like this gets it to work. Crazy further that the individual requests ``withCredentials:true`` had no impact on it.
Either way, thanks for figuring it out.

Comment: @UlysseBN did you find a way to get it to work with the option request?

Comment: @molerat in order to make it work with the option request, you need your server stating that your options requests are allowed to include such headers

Comment: After 2 days of research, this finally worked!

Answer (score 0):

Working example using [Danielo515's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43676021/7311767) answer:

```
import * as axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;


export function getAll() {
    const url = 'https://example.com';
    return axios.get(url);
}
```