# React native + Axios not persisting cookies across requests

Tags: android, react-native, fetch, axios

I have an react native app that talks to my Node server running on my laptop(http://192.168.x.x:3000). Even after performing an successful login, the consequent calls to my server fails with an 401 status. I see that no cookies are passed on the server.

Some observations:

1) My React Native app works just fine when i deploy my code to an actual server and use a proper domain(http://example.com) while making the API calls.

2) Using postman, I am able to authenticate myself and make consequent successful API calls to my local server.

This is a really strange issue and am sure I have missed out something small, but have been stuck with it for quite some time now.

Any hints/suggestions on what can be done?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Am having the same issue and tried the whole withCredentials:true stuff...

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to resolve this. I ended up purchasing a cloud VM and hosting & testing my service there.

Answer (score 0):

I recognize this is a little old, but if anyone is still facing issues, I found that the following steps resolved it for me

1. Include [withCredentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40941118/axios-wont-send-cookie-ajax-xhrfields-does-just-fine) on all requests from the react app
2. Used the [cors middleware](https://medium.com/@alexishevia/using-cors-in-express-cac7e29b005b) server side. Be sure to specify the `domain` (in my case, my VM's IP address with port) and set `credentials` to true
3. Increase the `maxAge` property -- I think the default was like 10 seconds so it kept seeming like my session wasn't persisting when in reality it was just expiring too fast.

An example for steps 2 and 3 might look something like:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const session = require('express-session');
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express();

// STEP 2
app.use(cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: '192.168.0.100:3000',
    methods:['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE']
}));

// STEP 3
app.use(session({
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 86400000 // one day
    }
}));
```

**EDIT:**
Also worth mentioning that if you're running your server on a virtual machine (like me) to be sure your virtual machine's date is consistent with the date of the device running your react app. I discovered the hard way that this also manifests as Axios appearing to lose sessions.