# Drupal and CORS request made by Axios: unable to check login status

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, cors, axios, drupal-8

I am creating standalone html/javascript application which should communicate with REST API of Drupal 8.6.2. My app uses Vue.js, so ajax requests are sent by Axios.

I want to be able to operate the app both on the same domain and via CORS from another domain. Let's say my Drupal sits on https://drupal8.example.org

I can login and logout from https://drupal8.example.org/app and from http://localhost/app without problem with the following code:

```
//Login
axios.post(
  "https://drupal8.example.org/user/login?_format=json",
  JSON.stringify({
    'name': "myusername",
    'pass': "mypassword"
}), {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/hal+json'
  },
  withCredentials: true
}).
then(function (response) {
  //my code goes here
});

// logout
axios.post(
  "https://drupal8.example.org/user/logout?_format=json&token=" + logout_token, {}, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/hal+json'
    },
    withCredentials: true
  }
).
then(function () {
  //my code goes here
})
```

But I am totally **unable to check by CORS if the user is logged in:**

```
//check login status
axios.get(
  "https://drupal8.example.org/user/login_status?_format=json", {}, {
    headers: {
      'crossDomain': true,
      'Content-Type': 'application/hal+json'
    },
    withCredentials: true
  }
).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data); // 1 from the same domain, 0 from localhost; should be 1 in both cases
});
```

If I check the url https://drupal8.example.org/user/login_status?_format=json in browser window, it displays **1**, but request made by CORS returns **0**.

What is the cause of problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Does the Drupal server response include the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials response header? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

Comment: It does:
`access-control-allow-credentials: true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, solution is pretty simple, but the cause is yet unknown to me. I had to **set default option for Axios**:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Apparently there is a big difference between `default.withCredentials` and `withCredentials` sent with individual requests. I do not know if it it is a bug or a feature...

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43676021/5249102) helped me to find the solution.